# I want to make custom array of object based on my result

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Basically i know array, and it's prototype methods,
I tried to get the result by using new Set(), map and filter.
but somehow i stuck at some point to get the desired result.

Below are the details about the problem and how i want the result.

#### Result I'm Getting

```js
let arr = [
  {
    Date: "2021-05-01",
    Status: "incomplete",
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-07",
    Status: "incomplete",
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-31",
    Status: "Complete",
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-31",
    Status: "incomplete",
  },
];
```

I want to convert this result like below,
NOTE : Based on Date.

```js
finalResult = [
  {
    Date: "2021-05-01",
    Incompleted: 1,
    Completed: 0,
    Total: 1,
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-07",
    Incompleted: 1,
    Completed: 0,
    Total: 1,
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-31",
    Incompleted: 1,
    Completed: 1,
    Total: 2,
  },
];
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR CONTRIBUTION

Comment: What have you tried to get the desired result?

Comment: @Reyno Yes, I tried till extracting unique dates, and then mathing status, but somehow i was stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it dynamic for any number of `status`.

- Create a `Set` of `status` to get all the unique status
- Create a partial object with all status as key and 0 as their value. There are many ways to create it. I'm using `Object.fromEntries`. It will look like this: `{ "incomplete": 0, "Complete": 0 }`
- Loop through the array. Use a `group` object with each `Date` as the key and object needed in the output as its value.

```js
const arr = [{Date:"2021-05-01",Status:"incomplete",},{Date:"2021-05-07",Status:"incomplete",},{Date:"2021-05-31",Status:"Complete",},{Date:"2021-05-31",Status:"incomplete",}],
      unique = new Set(arr.map(a => a.Status)),
      initial = Object.fromEntries( Array.from(unique, s => [s, 0]) ),
      group = { }

for (const { Date, Status } of arr) {
  group[Date] ||= { Date, ...initial, Total: 0 };
  group[Date][Status]++;
  group[Date].Total++
}

const output = Object.values(group)

console.log( output )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the combination of `Set` and `map` function. First, you will have to extract the unique dates from the array. We can use `map` to filter out dates and then use `Set` to keep only unique values. Learn more about sets from here : [JavaScript Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
const dates = [...new Set(arr.map(a => a.Date))]
```

Now we have the unique three dates in our `dates` array and we can easily iterate through each one and count `complete` and `incomplete` tasks on the following date.

```
const final = dates.map(date => {
    const incomplete = arr.filter(a => a.Date == date && a.Status == "incomplete").length
    const complete = arr.filter(a => a.Date == date && a.Status == "Complete").length

    return {
        Date: date,
        Incompleted: incomplete,
        Completed: complete,
        total: complete + incomplete
    }
})
```

Finally:-

```js
let arr = [
    {
        Date: "2021-05-01",
        Status: "incomplete",
    },
    {
        Date: "2021-05-07",
        Status: "incomplete",
    },
    {
        Date: "2021-05-31",
        Status: "Complete",
    },
    {
        Date: "2021-05-31",
        Status: "incomplete",
    },
];

const dates = [...new Set(arr.map( a => a.Date ))]
const final = dates.map( date => {
    const incomplete = arr.filter(a => a.Date == date && a.Status == "incomplete").length
    const complete = arr.filter(a => a.Date == date && a.Status == "Complete").length

    return {
        Date: date,
        Incompleted: incomplete,
        Completed: complete,
        total: complete + incomplete
    }
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: This solution has a suboptimal runtime especially for large objects. The problem is it traverses the array too often with the "filter" functions inside of the loop. It is O(M * 2N + N  + M) with M being the number of unique dates. If performance matters have a look at the "reduce" solution with O(N + M).

Comment: Yes, I am aware about that. Since this question looks very elementary, I tried to write the most "easy to understand" solution. I have plans to write an optimal solution if future if I can manage time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array `reduce` function for your problem. It traverses the array only once. We create a new object with the dates as the keys. If a date does not exist in the object yet, it creates a new empty entry for it. Afterwards it merges the existing entry with the current element.

Finally we need to turn it into an array again by using `Object.values`.

```js
const uniqueDates = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const existing = acc[cur.date] ?? createEmpty(cur);
  return {...acc, [cur.date]: merge(existing, cur) }
}, {})

const finalResult = Object.values(uniqueDates);

function createEmpty({ date }) {
  return { date, incompleted: 0, completed: 0, total: 0 }
}

function merge(existing, { status }) {
  return {
    ...existing,
    incompleted: existing.incompleted + status === 'incomplete',
    completed: existing.completed + status === 'Complete',
    total: existing.total + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use forEach loop for that...

```js
let arr = [
  {
    Date: "2021-05-01",
    Status: "incomplete",
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-07",
    Status: "incomplete",
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-31",
    Status: "Complete",
  },
  {
    Date: "2021-05-31",
    Status: "incompleted",
  },
]

let finalResult = []

const getDateEntryIndex = (date) => {
  let index = undefined

  finalResult.forEach((element, i) => {
    if(element.Date == date) {
      index = i
    }
  })

  return index
}

arr.forEach(element => {
  let index = getDateEntryIndex(element.Date)
  if(index) {
    if(element.Status == "Complete") {
      finalResult[index].Completed++
    } else {
      finalResult[index].Incompleted++
    }

    finalResult[index].Total++
  } else {
    finalResult.push({
      Date: element.Date,
      Incompleted: element.Status == "incompleted" ? 1 : 0,
      Completed: element.Status == "Complete" ? 1 : 0,
      Total: 1
    })
  }
})

console.log(finalResult)
```